# The k-add-button works only one times.

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-listview

The a href with k-add-button in the viewtemplate works only on times, not multible times. Have anybody a idea why, or mybe a sample or solution that's work correctly? 
If the k-add-button is outside from the template, it works fine.

```
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="viewtemplate">
    <div class='k-widget'>
        <span>Filter:</span><span>#:filtertext#</span><span>Filterwert:</span><span>#:filterwert#</span>
        <a class="k-button k-edit-button" ><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a>
        <a class="k-button k-delete-button" ><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>
        <a class="k-button k-add-button" ><span class="k-icon k-add"></span></a>            
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="editTemplate">
    <div class='k-widget'>
         <input type="text" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:filtertext" name="filtertext" required="required" validationMessage="required" />
         <span data-for="filtertext" class="k-invalid-msg"></span>
         <input type="text" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:filterwert" name="filterwert" required="required" validationMessage="required" />
         <span data-for="filterwert" class="k-invalid-msg"></span>
         <a class="k-button k-update-button" ><span class="k-icon k-update"></span></a>
         <a class="k-button k-cancel-button" ><span class="k-icon k-cancel"></span></a>
    </div>
</script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
              data: [ { filternr: 0, filtertext: "SA-Code", filterwert:"123"} ],
              schema: {
                  model: {
                   id: "filternr",
                   fields: {
                        filternr: { type: "number" },
                        filtertext: { type: "string" },
                        filterwert: { type: "string" }
                      }
                  }
              }
        });

        var listView = $("#example").kendoListView({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            template: kendo.template($("#viewtemplate").html()),
            editTemplate: kendo.template($("#editTemplate").html()),
        }).data("kendoListView");

        $(".k-add-button").click(function(e) {
            listView.add();
            e.preventDefault();
        });       


    }); // Ende $(document).ready()
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it on dojo.telerik.com ou jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code slightly at this dojo: [list view template with button](http://dojo.telerik.com/EWaJE)

You will hopefully notice the following changes I have made.

I have added a DataBound event to your listview object like so:

```
editTemplate: kendo.template($("#editTemplate").html()),
dataBound: onDataBound
```

I have then wrapped your button click event in the appropriate function called `onDataBound`

The reason the button is not working correctly is that once the data you have added to the dataSource is saved and then re-read the template is re-rendered and this then removes the event handlers from the buttons that you associated then with. In order to re-link them we reattach it as part of the dataBound event and then everything is working happily.

If you need more info let me know. 
Hopefully the example shows what it is doing.

Comment: glad this helped. Please feel free to mark this as the answer if you wouldn't mind. As I said if you need any more info in the answer let me know and I will be happy to update.